# How to create an excel file within the mobile application in Oracle MAF

Tags: android, excel, oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile, oracle-maf

I have a plan of developing a new mobile application for Android Platform (later for IOS also), so I opted Oracle MAF for developing my application. The final output of my application will be an excel file(either in .xsl or .xlsx formats).
How can we achieve this using Oracle MAF, are there any inbuilt API's for creating excel files?
Can we use the external libraries like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to create excel files?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use external libraries but the (current) problem is that MAF is using `Java 1.4` so your external library should be compatible with Java 1.4.

---

**Edit:**
As of `Oracle MAF 2.1` there is support for `Java 8` (Compact2 profile) which means that finding external libraries should be easier!